# Is it possible to deploy source from the Bitbucket to the Scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

We are working on implementation of ci/cd for 2nd generation package. Using CLI we want to:

1. Create scratch org and push the source from the branch to the scratch org.
2. Create package version from the branch source.

Is it possible?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) module on Trailhead, and the various CI/CD examples that Salesforce provides? [This one](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-bitbucket-package) is for BitBucket.

Comment: A similar discussion happened earlier this week on [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293629/lean-and-reusable-dx-bitbucket-pipeline-for-pr-checks)

Answer (score 0):

we can after a trigger on branch...

1. Authorize a Devhub org:
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm
2. let the pipeline run:

   sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a
3. wait for the scrach org to the created and once done let the pipeline run...

   sfdx force:source:push

I would strongly recommend using the jenkinsfile sample:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ci_jenkins_code.htm

Hope this helps!!